# Why am I getting errors while installing things using `npm`?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

Whenever I try to install anything using `npm` I always get this kind of message.

> found 7 vulnerabilities (3 moderate, 4 high)
> run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit`  for details

Generally, I use create-react-app to create react apps and I getting these errors there as well.

It worries me because generally the tutorials I follow, the instructors don't get these kinds of warnings.

The npm version I have installed is `6.14.13`

The node version I have installed is `v14.17.0`

I would like to know is there something wrong with the installation because of which I am getting these errors or there is some other problem.

If there is a way to fix this please let me know.

Also what does `npm audit fix` do, I have used it because the error says to run this command but I have no idea what it does.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-audit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everyone can create and publish npm package, which means it could potentially have malicious or vulnerable code included (e.g. https://www.zdnet.com/article/malicious-npm-packages-caught-installing-remote-access-trojans).

That's why npm introduced a way to warn you about packages with security issues. You can find more about that packages if you run npm audit. If you use well maintained and up-to-date packages, you usually won't end up in having these, but if you do, first check which vulnerabilities are present, and if they concern you.

npm audit fix tries to update dependencies version to fixed one, but it usually doesn't work very well.

Comment: I generally don't install random packages, only the ones my instructors tell me to, so I think they must not be malicious, so Is there something I should do to keep everything up to date and avoid these errors, as I mentioned being a beginner I won't really understand a lot by doing `npm audit` so it is better for me to avoid these vulnerabilities, so if there is a way please tell me I will try to keep everything up to date.

Comment: "npm audit fix" tries to update all dependencies, so if you don't want to bother, just run that command. If "npm audit fix" doesn't work, you should run "npm audit" and do some research about printed warnings if you want to be sure.